# What site characteristics generate stronger favimon?

Tags: favimon

In [Favimon](http://www.favimon.com), what characteristics of a website correlate to favimon stats?  E.g. Higher traffic affecting health or number of pages on the domain affecting attack.

Some sites (like Google) that I expected to be heavy hitters are surprisingly weak, so I'm looking for a more scientific method of finding strong favimon to capture. The Favimon FAQ briefly discusses this, but fails to give any useful details.

Comment: The FAQ makes it sound like "Whatever site the creator liked the most".  I think guessing which sites are powerful is supposed to be part of the game?

Comment: StackOverflow actually seems to be fairly powerful.  Nothing brings an opponent down like "Bad Advice".

Comment: @bwarner - Yeah, I noticed that too.

Comment: Google was disastrously powerful when I tried it the first time,but I had been playing for a while.  After that I tried it as my first challenge, and it was very weak.  I think they just build up in strength as you play longer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am the creator of Favimon!

The answers so far are more or less correct, it's mostly a site's position in the database that determines how high its stats are. The database is loosely organized - really popular websites are at the top, but otherwise it's basically a big list of websites that I am constantly adding to. Also, certain classes have their stats bumped in certain ways.

The actions each favimon has are based on the favimon's classes. But they are also randomized each time a favimon appears, so even though a site has a really powerful attack action, you might not get that action each time you play.

You can also randomly find favimon with special classes, like 'shiny', which have their stats bumped.

It's messy and esoteric, but it mostly works. In the future I may come up with something more sophisticated.

Thanks for your interest in my game!

Comment: Fun game, it was fun to stumble across it. Thanks for being part of this community too.

Comment: Always cool when a dev stops by!  Thanks for confirming this info.

Answer (score 10):

Ultimately, bwarner is correct. It is all manually driven by the developer currently.

As far as actually picking a site is concerned, I notice that the game has URL completion. If you type out at least three characters, it'll auto-complete URLs, which agrees with the FAQ entry regarding a special database of sites.

Example: Entering "tec" lists;

- techcrunch.com
- technorati.com
- and a bunch more that don't seem to be loading anymore, whoops.

Yet when I filled in "sha", nothing ever came up. oni provides what you'd expect (The Onion), wik provides the smorgasbord of wiki* sites.

It's not random, it's not even mapped, it's just the author's own input.

Comment: Why is in-game action not allowed, Mana? I'm assuming this goes back to the "editorializing" argument?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Mana's edit, it's just not really adding anything to the question or answer.

Comment: But I can't embed rich media into a comment :/.

Comment: You can link to it :) The `[link text](http://link/destination)` syntax is accepted in the comment box.